# Matplotlib cannot locate required library cycler on my installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have python 2.7 running on windows 8.1 with Eclipse as the IDE.  I am using the library PVLIB which uses matplotlib which in turn requires cycler.

A file cycler-0.10.0dist-info appears in my site-packages folder and reinstalling matplotlib shows the cycler reference is satisfied.

However, when I run a python script that includes the line `import matplotlib`, it generates the following error:

> "pydev debugger: starting (pid: 152) Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Eclipse\eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256\pysrc\pydevd.py",
> line 1530, in 
> globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File
> "C:\Eclipse\eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_5.1.2.201606231256\pysrc\pydevd.py",
> line 937, in run
> pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File "C:\Projects\PVLIBSandbox\SATPower.py", line 7, in
>
> import matplotlib as plt   File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py", line 124, in
>
> from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,   File "c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 34, in
>
> from cycler import Cycler, cycler as ccycler ImportError: No module named cycler

```
Running the code below is all that is needed to show this error.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pvlib as pv
import matplotlib as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct python binary?  It might be an issues of crossed paths.

Comment: I know it is Python 2.7 for Windows.  Anything else I should check?

Comment: I should point out that the python was downloaded from Python.org and installed with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling cycler using pip

Open up cmd and change directory to your python scripts directory i.e. Python2.7/Scripts and run

```
pip.exe install cycler
```

Comment: Already did this.  As I noted in my post  cycler-0.10.0dist-info is present in my site-packages directory and pip says the requirement is already satisfied.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I also tried reinstalling matplotlib.  It also indicated that the cycler requirement was met.

Comment: What happens if you just try to import cycler in a seperate file, can you do that?

Comment: Yes and the result is no different.

Comment: Can you see cycler in the list if you type help('modules') in a python terminal

Comment: No, cycler is not there although matplotlib is.  What does that mean?

Comment: BTW thanks for the tip on help('modules').  I did not know about that one.

Comment: https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/822 try the answer  about rebuilding matplotlib

Comment: Great catch Padskiiz.  I don't know why I did not see that when I was searching the web on my own.  The bad news is that I am running on Windows and the path forward is not clear at the moment.  Thanks though.

Comment: Actually, no.  I don't have time to work on rebuilding matplotlib.  I switched to another graphics package.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. But I figure out why. So beside those yellow packages, make sure you also have 3 extra files: cycler, pylab, and matplotlib-3.5.3-py3.10-nspkg (I use Pycharm btw.)

Copy those together with all yellow packages and paste them in site_packages (the one outside Lib)

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).